# Scheduling a task in App engine. Cron or task api is better?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, scheduled-tasks

I am new to app engine. I am using app engine python for my new project.
I want to schedule a task which will start and runs forever. Using that I want to check something like this

```
if smthng.expiry == time_now:
    smthng.expired = True
```

I want to perform this check in every second.

Which one is suitable for this, cron or task api ? is there any other way to do this?

it will be very helpful if I can take a look at some examples or tutorials showing how its done.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: you can't safely have a single task that runs forever as the machine it is running on may fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments above - the `task`s cannot run forever (a `task` must finish its job in 10 minutes otherwise it will be killed).

You could use `cron` but you need it to run every second and `cron`s can only run every minute.

You could also take a look at GAE's Modules and specifically at Modules with `Manual Scaling` (see more info here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/#Python_Instance_scaling_and_class ) which would allow you to create an infinite loop and wouldn't be affected by the 10 minute limit.